# how to run .apk files on Lubuntu 13.10?

Tags: 13.10, lubuntu, android

I have some .apk files and want to run on lubuntu 13.10. Please tell a detailed solution

Answer (score 1):

.apk extension is android application installation file 
cannot lunch on Ubuntu platform